# PYTHON: Pandas datetime index range to change column values

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe indexed using a 12hr frequency datetime:

```
                    id  mm ls
date            
2007-09-27 00:00:00 1   0   0
2007-09-27 12:00:00 1   0   0
2007-09-28 00:00:00 1   15  0
2007-09-28 12:00:00 NaN NaN 0
2007-09-29 00:00:00 NaN NaN 0
Timestamp('2007-09-27 00:00:00', offset='12H')
```

I use column 'ls' as a binary variable with default value '0' using:

```
data['ls'] = 0
```

I have a list of days in the form '2007-09-28' from which I wish to update all 'ls' values from 0 to 1.

```
                    id  mm ls
date            
2007-09-27 00:00:00 1   0   0
2007-09-27 12:00:00 1   0   0
2007-09-28 00:00:00 1   15  1
2007-09-28 12:00:00 NaN NaN 1
2007-09-29 00:00:00 NaN NaN 0
Timestamp('2007-09-27 00:00:00', offset='12H')
```

I understand how this can be done using another column variable ie:

```
data.ix[data.id == '1'], ['ls'] = 1
```

yet this does not work using datetime index. 
Could you let me know what the method for datetime index is?

Comment: IIUC doesn't `data.loc['2007-09-28','ls'] = 1` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of days in the form '2007-09-28':

```
days = ['2007-09-28', ...]
```

then you can modify your df using:

```
df['ls'][pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index.date).isin(days)] = 1
```

Comment: This works, as does "EdChum" comment, yet this answer creates a copy of the df, rather than updating the existing df. I didn't specify in the question however.